# Why does adding a source to an idle audiomixer increase the overall latency of the pipeline by a large amount?

Tags: gstreamer

Say I have a idle `audiomixer`. At some point in time, I decide to attach a live source to it.

When this happens, the entire latency of the pipeline begins to climb. For example:

1. Idle `audiomixer` with no sources attached - live pipeline latency is 50.
2. A live audio source is attached to the `audiomixer`, latency begins to climb over 5-10 seconds from 50 ms to 500 ms.

Something about adding a live source to the mixer causes a massive spike in latency that is sustained around 500 ms.

I've been browsing properties on the mixer:

1. start-time-selection
2. discont-wait
3. alignment-threshold
4. min-upstream-latency
5. ignore-latency-wait
6. ignore-inactive-pads

But whatever values im setting dont have an effect.